# Placeholder of Datepicker changes with selected date in react native, I want to make the placeholder constant, not changing

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am new to react native, I need a help.

I use a datepicker of native base in the react native, I place an icon at placeholder of that, when I click on the datepicker and select date the place holder icon changes with the selected date, so I want to make placeholder showing the icon only not the selected date, so how can I implement that.
My date picker code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Alert, Image, ScrollView, View, AppRegistry, StyleSheet, AsyncStorage, SafeAreaView, FlatList, ActivityIndicator, TouchableOpacity, Platform  } from 'react-native';
import { fetchUpdateAsync } from 'expo/build/Updates/Updates';
import DateTimePicker from "react-native-modal-datetime-picker";
import DateSelect from 'react-native-datepicker';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import moment from "moment";
import { Container, Header, Label, Button, Content, Item, Input, Textarea, DatePicker, Body, Title, Text, Icon, Picker, Form } from 'native-base';

var datepicker='';
var leavetype='';
var reason='';
var access_token_receieved='';
var chosenDate='';
var newDate='';
class RequestLeave extends Component {
    state = {choosenLabel: '', choosenindex: ''}
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            chosenDate:'',
            date: '',
            selected: undefined,
            datepicker:'',
            reason:'',
            leavetype:'',
         };
        this.setDate = this.setDate.bind(this);
    } 
    setDate(newDate)
    {
      this.chosenDate= new Date(),
      this.setState({ chosenDate: newDate });
    }
    onIconclick(){
      //this.setDate();
      chosenDate= new Date()
      this.setState({ chosenDate: newDate });
    }
    onValueChange(value) 
    {
        this.setState({choosenLabel: itemValue, choosenIndex: itemIndex})
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      AsyncStorage.getItem("token").then(async (res) => {
        access_token_receieved = await res;
        console.log('Access_Token from storage');
        console.log(access_token_receieved);
      });
        var that = this;
        var date = new Date().getDate(); //Current Date
        var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1; //Current Month
        var year = new Date().getFullYear(); //Current Year
        var hours = new Date().getHours(); //Current Hours
        var min = new Date().getMinutes(); //Current Minutes
        var sec = new Date().getSeconds(); //Current Seconds
        that.setState({
          //Setting the value of the date time
          date:
            date + '/' + month + '/' + year,
        });
    }
    fetchData(access_token_receieved) 
    {
      console.log('inside render');
      console.log('token inside :'+access_token_receieved);
      leavetype= this.state.choosenLabel;
      datepicker= this.state.chosenDate.toString().substr(3, 12);
      datepicker=moment(datepicker).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
      const { reason } = this.state;
      console.log(leavetype);
      console.log(datepicker);
      console.log(reason);
      console.log(access_token_receieved);
      var that = this;
      var url ='apiurl';
      console.log('url: '+url);
      fetch(url,{
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ access_token_receieved,
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            "datepicker":datepicker,
            "leavetype": leavetype,
            "reason": reason
          })
        })
        .then(response => {

            if(response.status == 200){
              Alert.alert('Leave Request send');
              //this.setTimeout(() => this.props.navigator.navigate('LeaveScreen'), 5000);
              setTimeout(
                () => { this.props.navigation.navigate('LeaveScreen') },
                2000
              )
            } else{
              Alert.alert('Leave Request not send');
            }
            console.log('result: '+response.status);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log("-------- error ------- "+error);
         alert("result:"+error)
        });
    }
    render() { 
      const { selectedStartDate } = this.state;
      const startDate = selectedStartDate ? selectedStartDate.toString() : '';
      const { navigation } = this.props.navigation; 
      return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.body}>

      <Text style={styles.taskItemHeader}>REQUEST LEAVE</Text>  
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainerRight}>
          <View >
          <Form>
            <Picker
              style={styles.taskItemContent}
              mode="dropdown"
              iosIcon={<Icon name="arrow-down" />}
              headerBackButtonText="Baaack!"
              selectedValue={this.state.choosenLabel}
              onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>  
                this.setState({choosenLabel: itemValue, choosenIndex: itemIndex})} 
            >
            <Picker.Item label="Leave Type"/>
            <Picker.Item label="Casual Leave" value="1" />
            </Picker>
            </Form>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity> 
      </View>

      <View style={styles.container1}>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainerRight}>
          <View style={styles.middlecontainer}>
            <View style={styles.calenderContainerLeft}>
                <DatePicker
                style={styles.datepickerstyle}
                date={this.state.date}
                showIcon={false}
                hideText={true} 
                format="DD-MM-YYYY"
                showIcon = {true}
                modalTransparent={false}
                animationType={"fade"}
                placeHolderText={<Icon type="FontAwesome" name='calendar' style={styles.iconstyle} onPress={() => this.setDate}/>}
                onDateChange={this.setDate}
                disabled={false}
              />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.calenderContainerRight}>
              <Text onPress={this.setDate}>
            <Text note numberOfLines={1} style={styles.dateItemContent} disabled>{this.state.chosenDate.toString().substr(4, 11)}</Text>
            </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>  
      </View>


      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.textinputContainerRight}>
          <TextInput style={styles.taskItemContent} multiline={true} placeholder='Reason for Leave..'></TextInput>
          </View> 
      </View>

      <View style={styles.btncontainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttoncontainer} onPress={() => this.fetchData(access_token_receieved)}>
          <View>
            <Body style={styles.bodyStyle}>
              <Text note numberOfLines={1} style={styles.buttontemContent}>APPLY</Text>
            </Body>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>


      </ScrollView>
    );

  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems:'center',
    alignContent:'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
    paddingBottom:15,
},

container1: {
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'row',
  alignItems:'center',
  alignContent:'center',
  justifyContent:'center',
  paddingBottom:15,
},

middlecontainer: {
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'row',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignContent: 'center',
  paddingBottom:15,
},

btncontainer: {
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'row',
  alignContent:'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  paddingBottom:15,
},

buttoncontainer: {
  flex: 1,
  backgroundColor:'#a0bfff',
    alignContent:'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
    marginLeft:15,
    marginTop:0,
    marginRight:15,
    marginBottom:0,
    height:60,
    borderRadius:10,
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.50,
    shadowRadius: 12.35,
    elevation: 10,
},

containerLast: {
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'row',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  paddingBottom:25,
},
iconstyle:{
  fontSize: 35,
  color: '#a0bfff',
},
taskItemContent: { 
  color: 'black',
  fontSize: 15,
  marginLeft:10,
},
dateItemContent:{
  color: 'black',
  fontSize: 15,
  marginLeft:10,
},

datepickerstyle:{color:'white'},

buttontemContent: { 
  color: 'white',
  fontWeight:'bold',
  fontSize: 15,
  alignItems:'center',
},

bodyStyle:{
  borderWidth:0,
  justifyContent:'center',
},

textbodyStyle:{
  borderWidth:0,
  justifyContent:'center',
  alignContent:'flex-start',
},

taskItemHeader: { 
  color: 'black',
  fontSize: 25,
  alignContent:'flex-start',
  paddingBottom:15,
  paddingLeft:15,
},
buttonContainerLeft: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems:'center',
    alignContent:'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
    marginLeft:15,
    marginTop:0,
    marginRight:0,
    marginBottom:0,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    height:120,

    borderRadius:8,
    shadowColor: "#000",
shadowColor: "#000",
shadowOffset: {
  width: 0,
  height: 0,
},
shadowOpacity: 0.50,
shadowRadius: 12.35,
elevation: 10,
},
buttonContainerRight: {
    flex: 1,
    alignContent:'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
    marginLeft:15,
    marginTop:0,
    marginRight:15,
    marginBottom:0,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    height:60,
    borderRadius:8,
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.50,
    shadowRadius: 12.35,
    elevation: 10,
},

textinputContainerRight: {
  flex: 1,
  alignContent:'flex-start',
  marginLeft:15,
  marginTop:0,
  marginRight:15,
  marginBottom:0,
  backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  height:160,
  borderRadius:8,
  shadowColor: "#000",
  shadowColor: "#000",
  shadowOffset: {
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
  },
  shadowOpacity: 0.50,
  shadowRadius: 12.35,
  elevation: 10,
},

viewstyle1:{
  alignItems:'flex-start',
  alignContent:'center',
  justifyContent:'center',
},
viewstyle2:{
  alignItems:'flex-end',
  alignContent:'center',
  justifyContent:'center',
},

calenderContainerRight: {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent:'center',
  alignItems:'flex-end',
  marginLeft:15,
  marginTop:0,
  marginRight:5,
  marginBottom:0,
  height:60,
  borderRadius:8,
},

calenderContainerLeft: {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent:'center',
  marginLeft:5,
  marginTop:0,
  marginBottom:0,
  height:60,
  borderRadius:8,
},

calenderContainerRight1: {
  flex: 1,
  alignItems:'center',
  alignContent:'center',
  alignContent:'center',
  height:60,
  borderRadius:8,
},

textContainerRight: {
  flex: 1,
  alignItems:'center',
  alignContent:'center',
  justifyContent:'center',
  marginLeft:15,
  marginTop:0,
  marginRight:15,
  marginBottom:0,
  backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  height:120,
  borderRadius:8,
  shadowColor: "#000",
shadowColor: "#000",
shadowOffset: {
width: 0,
height: 0,
},
shadowOpacity: 0.50,
shadowRadius: 12.35,
elevation: 10,
},

btn:{
  borderRadius:0,

},
body:{
  paddingTop:15,
  paddingBottom:30,
  backgroundColor: '#efefef',
}
});
export default RequestLeave
```

So can someone please help me with this.

[image]

[image]

these are the out put pages, as I don't want to show date at the left side, there I want to show the icon only.

Comment: So basically you want to show icon on left when you select date?

Comment: I want the icon should remain there even after selecting the date i don't want the date appear there, i have placed a text to show the date.

Comment: Do you have any expo project where I can see the code?

Comment: I don't have an expo project

Comment: I can send the code of the page, is that enough

Comment: I have now pasted the entire code in that page, can anyone please help me.

Comment: Instead of using datepicker placeholder text, add a view on the left.

Comment: I have made some changes in the code, by using the reference of the datepicker to be called from the button click, I am getting error as: TypeError: Cannot read property 'onPress' of undefined.

Comment: <DatePicker
                style={styles.datepickerstyle}
                date={this.state.date}
                showIcon={false}
                hideText={true} 
                format="DD-MM-YYYY"
                showIcon = {true}
                modalTransparent={false}
                animationType={"fade"}
                placeHolderText='Select Date'
                onDateChange={(date) => {this.setState({date: date})}}
                disabled={false}
                ref={(picker) => { this.datePicker = picker; }}
               
              />

Comment: myFunction2()  {
      console.log("-------- error ------- ");
      Alert.alert('Right button pressed')
      this.myButton.onPress()
      //this.myButton.props.onPress();
      //this._touchable.onPress();
    }
    setDate(newDate)
    {
      this.chosenDate= new Date(),
      this.setState({ chosenDate: newDate });
    }

Comment: Can you update your code in post?